# Bind checkbox to value instead of true/false with reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm trying to get a simple example working using reactive/model driven forms. I want to bind an array of checkboxes to a list of values, and not a list of boolean values.

This plunker shows the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/a9OdMAq2YIwQFo7gixbj?p=preview The values bound to the forms are booleans, I'd like the answer to be something like `["value1", "value2", etc]`

I have something like this, but I don't know how to get the result that I want?

The template:

```
<form [formGroup]="checkboxGroup">
    <input *ngFor="let control of checkboxGroup.controls['myValues'].controls" 
    type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" value="value-1" [formControl]="control" />
</form>
```

And the component:

```
let checkboxArray = new FormArray([
  new FormControl({checked: true, value: "value1"}),
  new FormControl({checked: false, value: "value2"}))]);

this.checkboxGroup = _fb.group({
  myValues: checkboxArray
});
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

A checkbox value is either checked ( true ) or not checked ( false ).
Generally speaking, doesn't make sense for a checkbox to have another value but if you want to do this nonetheless , you'd need to write your own Checkbox Value Assessor .

Comment: care to elaborate further?  If I google [CheckboxValueAssessor](https://www.google.com/search?q=angular2+CheckboxValueAssessor) I get this answer.

Comment: My *model* might require a string of `'Y'` or `'N'`, so why shouldn't I be able to dynamically set its `[checked]` and `[value]` properties and retain the string within my `[(ngModel)]`?

Comment: This is frustrating to me and I don't understand why Angular made it this way.  [According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#value), HTML can have a value and it's only ever submitted if the element is "checked" (value isn't limited to bool). It works in Angular if you set it initially, but once you manually click the checkbox once, the value is lost and converted to a simple boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Angular.js (1.x) had ng-true-value and ng-false-value, which was convenient to avoid conversions between the web form and an inflexible backend:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="vv[name]" ng-true-value="'1'" ng-false-value="'0'"/>
```

Angular 2+ has the banana-in-a-box notation to bind directly to the model, but that data type must be boolean to work with a checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="vv[name]"/>
```

If you really can't use booleans, the [checked] and (change) notation is a workable substitute (in this case, 1 is true, 0 is false):

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="vv[name]==='1'"                                            
    (change)="vv[name]=$event.target.checked?'1':'0'"/>
```