# How to bind value of checkbox to formControl in Angular 2.1.0?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

when I bind a formControl to the input element of type checkbox it gives me the state of checkbox instead of its value. is there any way to bind formControl to the value.

here is a sample code with output.

**the template file**

```
<div>
    <form [formGroup]="myForm">
        <div>
            <label>Option1</label>
            <input type="checkbox"
                   [formControl]="myForm.controls['option1']"
                   value="value1">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Option2</label>
            <input type="checkbox"
                   [formControl]="myForm.controls['option2']"
                   value="value2">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Option3</label>
            <input type="checkbox"
                   [formControl]="myForm.controls['option3']"
                   value="value3">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Option4</label>
            <input type="checkbox"
                   [formControl]="myForm.controls['option4']"
                   value="value4">
        </div>
    </form>
    <!-- debug the value of form -->
    <pre>
        {{myForm.value | json}}
    </pre>
</div>
```

**output**

[image: output of the sample form]

When I print the value of `myForm` i get the state of checkbox.

is it possible to bind the formControl to the `value` property of checkbox so that i can get that inside value object of `FormGroup` as follows?

```
{
   option1:null,
   option2:value2,
   option3:null,
   option4:value4,
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting 'name' attr for each input elem?

Comment: What to do you mean ?

Comment: @Milad I am asking that when i bind a `FormControl` to checkbox the `FormControl` get bind to the state of checkbox and gives me true or false as the value instead of giving me the actual value of checkbox which i have set using the _value_ attribute.In other form element such as text input the `FromControl` is bind with the value of text input. so how do i do that with the checkbox control in my form.

Comment: @HirenParekh http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41084488/bind-checkbox-to-value-instead-of-true-false-with-reactive-forms/41085133#41085133