# Bind CheckBox list from ID in angular 6

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular5

I am using a checkBox list here is my list

```
   <div *ngFor="let x of rolesArr">
   <input type="checkbox" value="{{x.Id}}" (change)="changeModel($event, rolesArr, x.Id)" [(ngModel)]="x.checked" formControlName="Roles" />
 <label>{{x.Name}}</label>
</div>
```

and the array  which i am using it to bind is

```
this.rolesArr = [
            { Id: 1, Name: 'Role-Send Push Notification'},
            { Id: 2, Name: 'Role-Course Creation and Preview'},
            { Id: 3, Name: 'Role-Course Publishing'},
            { Id: 4, Name: 'Role-Mobile User Management'},
        ];
```

I am saving the comma seperated values into database and while i am getting the vales i am unable to bind it again
I am getting the values **like this '1','2'**
so how can i bind the checkbox list using its Id

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bind checkbox to value instead of true/false with reactive forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41084488/bind-checkbox-to-value-instead-of-true-false-with-reactive-forms)